# How to find an extreme feasible point in a linear polytope (set $\{x : Ax \leq b\}$ defined by halfspaces)?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, polytopes

The set $$\mathcal P = \{x : Ax \leq b\}$$ is a linear polytope (or, more precisely, an $H$-polytope) and is defined as the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces.

The simplex method for the linear program optimizes over a polytope

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min_{x\in \mathbb R^n} &c^Tx\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & Ax \leq b
\end{array}
$$

and initializes by finding an extreme point, e.g $\bar x$ where $A\bar x \leq b$, and $A_I\bar x = b_I$ for a set of row indices $I$ of length $n$, and $A_I$ is invertible.

Suppose that such an $A_I$ exists. Are there any systematic or commonly accepted ways of finding an extreme feasible point? Even if it's a crappy way, are there any ways that are used in practice? I found many references on how to proceed once the feasible point is found, but not how to pick it to begin with.

Thank you!

Comment: I updated the title to include the definition, but a linear polytope is just the set of vectors $x$ satisfying the constraint $Ax \leq b$.

Comment: I would call that an $\mathcal H$-polytope, since it's defined by the intersection of **h**alf-spaces. This is standard terminology.

Comment: Ok, I added a clarification in the question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to introduce slack variables $s$, i.e., $Ax +  s = b$.  Define $s = s^+ - s^-$ with $s^+ \geq 0$ and $s^- \geq 0.$ And consider for objective function $\min_{s,x} 1^Ts^-$. In other words,  solve

\begin{array}{ll}
\min_{s, x} & 1^T s^-\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & Ax + s= b\\
 & s = s^+ - s^-\\
 & s^+, s^- \geq 0\\
\end{array}

Then, $s = b$ with $x = 0$ is a solution for that particular problem. Now, if the optimal value is $0$, then $s^- = 0$, hence the corresponding $x$ verifies $Ax \leq b$, and therefore is a solution to your original problem. If the optimal value is not $0$, then your original problem is not feasible.

Comment: So the idea is, this LP I CAN solve, because there exists an intuitive initialization, and the solution gives me an initialization for the LP I am actually trying to solve?  Actually that makes a lot of sense; thank you!

Comment: That is correct!